# Grub doesn't find windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub

So, i've recently installed Debian in dual boot with Windows 8. When I reboot, my GRUB doesn't show Windows 8. My initial question is : How do i know if Windows 8 is still existing. If it is, how to add it in the GRUB. If not, what to do?

I'm going to show you some commands:

cat /proc/cpuinfo:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 876.281
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.36
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 801.468
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.36
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 822.281
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.36
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 800.156
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.36
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

fdisk -l:

```
Disque /dev/sda : 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 octets, 1465149168 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x1a48fb9c

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 1465145343 1465143296 698,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disque /dev/sdb : 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 octets, 234441648 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0xdcc1cf69

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048  19531775  19529728   9,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       19533822 234440703 214906882 102,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       19533824  28186623   8652800   4,1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       28188672 234440703 206252032  98,4G 83 Linux
```

Maybe, should I write a few more commands?

EDIT: Well I did install Debian after Win8, but my main issue was that I installed Debian over Win8. So Grub didn't find Win8, because Win8 wasn't there anymore.

Comment: Did you install Debian before or after Windows?

Comment: I installed Debian after Windows

Comment: Try reinstalling GRUB on Debian keeping Windows disk present (`grub-install /dev/sdb`)

Comment: I wrote this command line: I got No error. After reboot, I still have only Debian

Answer (score 1):

Configure your grub file.
`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` .It will find your windows boot manager and add boot menu entry for EFI configuration. 
Reboot the system.

Comment: Actually, at the time I asked this question, I didn't have win8 anymore, I installed Debian over it.

Comment: In case of dual boot with Debian or Debian based distribution, install and write everything to file and don't install grub now, make a UEFI bootable USB disk of "system rescue CD" and then install grub and configure it. Never install grub at the disk partitioning because it overwrites entries in gpt files and may harm Windows EFI files.